# querying records that have revisions related to them

Tags: php, sql, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I created a commenting system that allow users to submit comments on each item.

It turned into bit of a project/scope creep and now I need to implement the ability for users to edit their original comments and keep track of those comments.

All comments are located in the comments table

```
comments: id, comment, item_id, timestamp
```

Now that revisions must be tracked, I created a new table titled revisions:

```
comment_id, revision_id, timestamp
```

All comments (new or old) are entered into the comments table, if the user decides to revise an existing comment, it will be entered as a new record in the comments, then recorded into the revisions table. Once the new comment is entered into the comments table, it will take the id that was created and pass it into the revisions.reivison_id, and it will populate revisions.comment_id with the id of the original comment the user revised (hope I didn't lose you).

Now I've come to the problem I need help with: I need to display a list of all comments for a specific item, which would have a query of something like

```
select * from comments where item_id = 1
```

Now that I added the revisions table, I need to retrieve a list of comments for the specific item (just like the above query does) and (and heres the kicker) if any comment is revised, I need to return the most recent version of that comment.

What is the best way of accomplishing this?

I thought about running two queries, one to retrieve all the comments in the comments table, store in an array, and another query to return all records within the revisions table where I would set revisions.comment_id to be distinct and would only want to return the more recent one

the revisions query might look something like this

```
select comment_id DISTINCT, revision_id, timestamp 
from revisions order by timestamp desc
```

What is the best way of only displaying the most recent version of each comment (some will have revisions and most won't)?

I am not a sql expert, so it might be accomplished using sql or will I need to run two different queries, store data into separate arrays, then run thru each array, compare and strip out the older versions of that comment? example (part in theory) below

```
foreach($revisions as $r):
 $comments = strip key/value from comments array where $r['comment_id'] is 
 found in comments array
endforeach;

return $comments; // return the comments array after it was stripped of the older comments
```

I imagine if there was a way of running one query to only return a list of the most recent versions of a comment is the best practice, if so, could you provide the appropriate query for that, otherwise is the two queries into two arrays and striping out values from the comments array the best way or a better way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

First off, I'll add two alternative *approaches* and then I'll edit with a query to deal with your current schema.

Option 1 - Add a `deleted` flag to your comments.  When a comment is revised, do as you already do but also mak the original as deleted.  Then you just need `WHERE deleted = 0` wher you want active comments.

Option 2 - Change your revision table to be a clone of the comment table, plus an additional field for when the revision was made.  Now, whenever you revise a comment, don't create a new record in comment, just update the existign row and add a new row to the revisions table.  This is easily maintained with a trigger and is a very standard auditting pattern.

**EDIT** Option 3 - A query to cope with your schema.

As described, if I make a comment, then edit it twice (with no other activity), I get something like this...

```
 id |   comment    | item_id | timestamp
----+--------------+---------+-----------
  1 |   Hello,     |    1    |  13:00
  2 |   World!     |    1    |  14:00
  3 | Hello, World |    1    |  15:00

comment_id | revision_id | timestamp
-----------+-------------+-----------
    1      |       2     |    14:00
    2      |       3     |    15:00
```

Base on this, the live comment is the only one without an entry in the revision table...

```
SELECT *
FROM   comment
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM revision WHERE comment_id = comment.id)
  AND  item_id = @item_id
```

Comment: I like option 1. This really involves about 8 tables but I used two tables as an example, otherwise I would of confused myself trying to explain it.